# Twython get_retweets method gives error on number or arguments

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twython

I am trying to replicate the example shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741339/fetch-the-retweets-for-the-tweets-using-python), and I am stumbling in what looks like a `Twython` bug, appreciate any insight

Here's the code:

```
status_id = <some_status_id>
response = twitter.get_retweets(status_id, 100)
```

which results in the following error

```
TypeError: get_retweets() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I tried to run without arguments as in

```
response = twitter.get_retweets()
```

and then I get an error from Twitter saying

```
twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 404 (Not Found), Sorry, that page does not exist
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the `status_id` must be passed as a named parameter

```
status_id = <some_status_id>
response = twitter.get_retweets(id=status_id) # 100 is already the max available
```